# Is there PyQt5 on 32-bit Linux?

Tags: python, linux, qt, pyqt5, 32-bit

I searched high and low, and on the riverbank site it says

> Wheels are provided for Python v3.5 and later for 64-bit Linux, macOS and 32-bit and 64-bit Windows

Is there any way to get PyQt5 on 32-bit Linux?

Comment: Which specific linux distro are you using? If it doesn't provide 32-bit binary packages, you will have to [compile them yourself](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#building-and-installing-from-source).

Comment: debian stretch - i assume compiling them myself would be very complicated?

Comment: I really cannot see what the problem is here: why don't you just install the [i386 packages provided by debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python3-pyqt5)?

Comment: oh damn, i thought no wheels means no support - thanks!